# When i call method has a for loop it returns one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    def pagination():
        pagination = range(1, 5)
        for p in pagination:
            page = f"https://www.xx.xx{p}"
            return (page)
```

when I call the method  it doesn't loop  and It only returns this line https://www.xx.xx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return stops the whole function, therefore the loop is immediatly terminated. Try using a list and appending onto that. At the end you can return this list.

Comment: so return stop the loop I have to print it or append the results to list right?

Answer (score 0):

You have a return in your for loop that will end it immediately and return from the function.

Comment: so what to do to print the for loop just use print or do you have another way?

Comment: If all you want is to print then just print each page as you get it.  You can also put the pages into a list if you plan to use the values later for some other purpose.